# Space between label and caption in table of figures Overleaf

Tags: latex, overleaf

In table of figures I have a problem where there is no space between figure number and figure caption in table of figures if number is more than 1 digit. The capture below describes the problem.

:[image: See Here]

Comment: please make a [mre]

Comment: The answer will depend on your documentclass, the packages you use and the mechanism you employ for the list of figures. Without a mre, we can only guess an answer and it might or might not work for your document.

Comment: my documents class is report

Comment: please make a [mre]!!

Answer (score -1):

Hi I solved this by adding \hspace to figure's caption

```
 \caption{\hspace{0.1 cm} titleoffigure}
```